# How to implement workflow dependent on two custom objects

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, workflow

I have Master Object Scheme__c under that I have 2 custom objects
1. SchemeStage__c (Schedule Date, StageName = 'Registration')
&
2. Registration__c (which has Registration Date, User which registers for scheme)

I want to design a workflow :
When a scheme has passed the Stage-date and nobody has registered for the scheme, a notification should go out to the publisher to notify them that no registrations have occurred

Comment: Hey Saurabh, welcome to SFSE. You've done a good job articulating your desired state, but you'll find that people here are most receptive if you can narrow down your post to one specific question that the community can help you address.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a roll-up count on your Master Object `Scheme__c` of `Registration__c.User` so you'll know how many registered Users you have at any given moment in time. Assuming a Master-Detail relationship doesn't exist between `Scheme__c` and `Registration__c`, that's best done using a roll-up trigger to populate a custom field on `Scheme__c`. If a M-D relationship exists, then you can use a roll-up summary field to do the job.

Using that and a look-up to the `SchemeStage__c.StageDate` (did you mean StageName in your question?), you'll be able to create a workflow rule that sends an email to the publisher with the number of registered Users when the Registration Stage ends, or if you need to, you should be able to send it at a specified number of days from the date at which the stage begins or ends (the latter being done using time-based workflow).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valueable feedback, Roll-up summary worked out really well.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. If this post led you to solving your issue, please help the rest of the community by marking it as having answered your question.